# Find the value of $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} 2^{\frac{k}{n+k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Okay, I know this question is very easy. As a matter of fact, I have previously solved it myself. However, I have not practised this in a while, so I having trouble getting started.

**WHAT I DO KNOW**

That the two Sigmas as be separated for n and k, but I am not able to split the fraction to get the constituent parts.

The answer is 2
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like for $n,k$ large the summand is still finite, this implies that the series is divergent.

Comment: It’s is solvable though. The answer is 2

Comment: Perhaps you are using a different summation method? The limit of large $n$ and $k$ gives a value greater than 0 so I'm not sure that this sum converges through traditional means?

Comment: If you want to blindly work through this, maybe you could try something like switching the summations to being over $n+k$ and $n-k$ the $n-k$ gives you a power series (which I guess we ignore convergence of) and then sum the results of that?

Comment: There must be an error in the problem statement as given. Every term of the sum is greater than 1, so it cannot converge.

Comment: I will check the question again, and if there are any errors, I will correct. I am 99% sure though that this is the right question